# Inconsistencies between hexagonal and rectangular binning with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, hex, bin

I recently updated RStudio and all packages to newest versions. Suddenly geom_hex starts doing weird things.

MWE of the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(MASS)
df=as.data.frame(mvrnorm(n=10000,mu=c(0, 0),Sigma=matrix(c(5, 3, 4, 4), ncol=2)))
ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+geom_hex(bins=100)
ggplot(df,aes(V1,V2))+geom_bin2d(bins=100)
```

And I get the following two plots:

[image: hex]
[image: bin2d]

What is going on?

Comment: Latest ggplot2 version has a bug with hex bins. See https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/5037